# Proving $\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{2\cdot \ln(x+1)} = \frac{1}{2}$ with $\epsilon- \delta$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Today, I spent some hours trying to solve this problem but I can't reach the conclusion:

> Show with $\epsilon-\delta $ definition the following limit:
> $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{2\cdot \ln(x+1)} = \frac{1}{2}$$

So, first of all, I set up the inequality:
$$\left|\frac{\ln(x)}{2\cdot \ln(x+1)}-\frac{1}{2}\right|<\epsilon$$

Then:
$$\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon<\frac{\ln(x)}{2\cdot \ln(x+1)}<\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon \implies (1-2\epsilon)\cdot \ln(x+1) < \ln(x) < (1+2\epsilon)\cdot \ln(x+1)$$

And elevating with base $e$ to cancel the $\ln(x)$:

$$(x+1)^{1-2\epsilon}<x<(x+1)^{1+2\epsilon}$$

I want to apply the limit $\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{(1+f(x))^\alpha-1}{\alpha\cdot f(x)}=1$ with $f(x) \to_{x \to 0} 0$. So, I have:

$$x^{1-2\epsilon}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1-2\epsilon}<x<x^{1+2\epsilon}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1+2\epsilon}$$

Then:

$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
x>x^{1-2\epsilon}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1-2\epsilon}
\\ x<x^{1+2\epsilon}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{x} \right )^{1+2\epsilon}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

So:
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
x^{2\epsilon} - 1>\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1-2\epsilon} - 1
\\ \frac{1}{x^{2\epsilon}}-1<\left(1+\frac{1}{x} \right )^{1+2\epsilon}-1
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
When $x$ approaches $+\infty$:
$$
\sim
\left\{\begin{matrix}
x^{2\epsilon}-1>\frac{1-2\epsilon}{x}
\\\frac{1}{x^{2\epsilon}}-1<\frac{1+2\epsilon}{x}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Notice that the second inequality is always true because $\frac{1}{x^{2\epsilon}}\to 0^+$ when $x \to +\infty$, so that left side is negative while right side $\frac{1-2\epsilon}{x}$ is positive.

Now, in some way I have to find $\delta = N$. I noticed that: $$x^{2\epsilon}-1\sim x^{2\epsilon} \;\;\; x \to +\infty$$

and then for the first inequality:
$$x^{2\epsilon}>\frac{1-2\epsilon}{x} \implies x> \delta(\epsilon)= N =(1-2\epsilon)^{1+2\epsilon}$$

Here, tere is a problem because when $\epsilon \to 0^+$, $\delta = N \to 1$ and not to $+\infty$. Is this anyway correct? Or, I can't apply asympothics reduction with $\epsilon - \delta$?

**Edit:**
I  all three solutions proposed, $\delta = N$ goes to infinity when $\epsilon \to 0^+$. In my answer, $N$ tends to $1$, so is my solution not corret? If it's yes, why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Fix $x>e^2-1$. Using
$$ \ln(1+\frac1x)<\frac1x $$
we have
$$ \left|\frac{\ln(x)}{2\cdot \ln(x+1)}-\frac{1}{2}\right|=\frac12\frac{\ln(1+\frac1x)}{\ln(x+1)}<\frac{1}{4x}. $$
Then for $\forall \varepsilon>0$, denote $N$ by $N=\max\{e^2-1,\frac1{4\varepsilon}\}$. Then when $x>N$,
$$ \left|\frac{\ln(x)}{2\cdot \ln(x+1)}-\frac{1}{2}\right|<\varepsilon. $$

Comment: thanks for you answer. My question is: how did you obtain that inequality? Thanks.

Comment: Which inequality?

Comment: The first one: $\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)<\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Using $e^x>1+x$, it is easy to get it.

Comment: Ok. Now I see it. I don't understand one thing: is my solution globally correct? Because in all your three solution, I see $\delta$ or $N$ always tends to $+\infty$, but my $\delta$ doesn't. Why? I will add this as an edit, so everyone are goig to read it.

Comment: I think something is wrong in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $\log_{x+1}x\stackrel{x\to+\infty}\to1$, we need to find $N$ such that $|\log_{x+1}x-1|<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ and $x>N$. This is equivalent to $(x+1)^{1-\epsilon}<x<(x+1)^{1+\epsilon}$ where the upper bound is obvious. The lower bound is also obvious when $\epsilon\ge1$ (take $N>1$), and when $0<\epsilon<1$, Bernoulli's inequality gives $(x+1)^{1-\epsilon}\le1+(1-\epsilon)x$ so taking $N>1/\epsilon$ completes the proof.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have understood the first part of your answer. $1+2\epsilon >1$, so $x^{1+2\epsilon}>x^1$. I don't understand the part of Bernoulli's inequality. $1-\epsilon$ is not an integer, do we have a generalized Bernoulli's inequality?

Comment: Yes, we have $(1+x)^r\le 1+rx$ for $r\in[0,1]$ and $x\in[-1,\infty)$ which has a [simple AM-GM proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Alternative_proof).

Comment: if I have to show this thing without using Bernoulli's inequality, is my method correct? After all, also I have shown that $x>\delta(\epsilon)$ is a solution. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I had not the patience to read through all what you did but here is a way to prove the limit with elementary arguments: the intuition is indeed that $\ln(x)$ and $\ln(1+x)$ are big and close to each other. Instead of calculating the ratio, let us look at the difference:

$$\ln(1+x) - \ln(x) = \ln\left( \frac{1+x}{x}\right)= \ln\left(1+ \frac{1}{x}\right) < \frac{1}{x}\quad \text{for}\quad x > 0$$
(graph of $\ln(1+t)$ below its tangent at $t=1$ because the function is concave. Can also be seen with the analytic expansion). From here, one has
$$ 1 - \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(1+x)} < \frac{1}{x\, \ln(1+x)}\quad \Longrightarrow\quad 1 - \frac{1}{x\, \ln(1+x)} < \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(1+x)} $$
(and r.h.s. is obviously smaller than $1$). Since $x\, \ln(1+x)\to \infty$ when $x\to\infty$, the inverse $\frac{1}{x\, \ln(1+x)} \to 0$

Comment: This isn't an epsilon argument as requested (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1693891/471884) for a non-epsilon duplicate).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Sorry but what comes to my mind is "When a wise man points at the moon the imbecile examines the finger". I guess that one can easily add the $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ behind a statement like $\frac{1}{X} \to 0$ when $X\to\infty$

Comment: You've computed $1=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\left(1-\frac1{x\ln(1+x)}\right)\le\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(1+x)}\le\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}1.$ @TheSimpliFire is right and you shouldn't be condescending to experienced users, especially when they give constructive criticism.